# Umlauts or other special characters in TpX

Tags: fonts, graphics, accents, eps

I'm using [TpX](http://ctan.org/pkg/tpx) to create EPS graphics to be displayed in documents or presentations. At the moment, I'm preparing a presentation in German using the `beamer` class and include figures via the `\includegraphics` command, which works fine.

There is one problem, however. When I insert a text into my figure using TpX, it will display the umlaut, which is also retained in the corresponding `.tpx` file. But in the presentation, which uses the `epstopdf` package, the umlaut is missing and replaced by a rather ugly box when inserting the figure via `\includegraphics{figure.eps}`. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[babel]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

...TITLE INFORMATION...

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{figure.eps}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I open the `.eps` file as is, the space where the umlaut is supposed to appear is just empty, without a box around it. Then, in the compiled PDF presentation file, there is the aforementioned box. Umlauts that I enter in the LaTeX file itself are fine and appear as intended. Note that, in TpX, I have also tried to replace the umlaut with its equivalent, such as `\"{a}`. However, this will be rendered as `\"{a}`, not as the corresponding umlaut, so this does not solve the problem? Does anyone know of a possible solution? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable (minimum working) example to your post? It would help a lot. Just an idea: Have you tried `\documentclass[babel]{beamer}`? I'm sorry that's not the case of TeX, but TpX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please also add your figure.eps or something similar. I am not using TpX and can't reproduce what you are doing. Your MWE should contain just one frame with your EPS and the minimum of packages to show your error.

Comment: Thank you, I have now edited my post so as to provide more background.

Comment: What happens if you add the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble of your beamer document? Separately, does using `utf8` instead of `latin1` as the option for the `inputenc` package help? Finally, in most moern TeX distributions it shouldn't be necessary to load the `epstopdf` package explicitly; let `graphicx` do that job for you.